# Notice: map_meta_cap was called incorrectly

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, wp-load.php

I created an external script to import json data into a custom post type that uses wp-load.php. Everything works fine but after every update I get the message

```
Notice: map_meta_cap was called incorrectly. The post type EXAMPLE is not registered, so it may not be reliable to check the capability "edit_post" against a post of that type.
```

Im calling the script inside a child theme and post_type_exists returns false but works fine...

Ive seen a similar notice in a core track thread but it talks about comments being the issue and my post type doesnt have any comment functionality.

```
function child_post_types() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Courses', 'Post Type General Name', 'test' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Course', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'test' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Courses', 'test' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Course:', 'test' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Courses', 'test' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Course', 'test' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Course', 'test' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'test' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Course', 'test' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Course', 'test' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Courses', 'test' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'test' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'test' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Course', 'test' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Courses', 'test' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'revisions', 'author' ), //editor, thumbnail, title, author, excerpt, trackpacks, custom-fields, comments, revisions, page-attributes, post-formats 
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             =>array('slug'=>'courses'),
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'course', $args );

}    
add_action( 'init', 'child_post_types', 0 );
```

And the script is sitting in my child theme just getting a local json file and looping through courses with wp_update_post()

```
require('../../../wp-load.php');

$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'wp-content/themes/_theme/courses.json' ), true );

foreach($data as $key => $c){

  $course = wp_update_post( array(
                'ID'    => $courseID, 
                'post_title' => $c['CourseTitle'],
                'post_content' => $c['Description'],
            ), true );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it says `The post type EXAMPLE is not registered`. where come this CPT from ?

Comment: @mmm its just an example the actual post type is called course and its defined in my child theme loaded into functions.php

Comment: Without seeing some real code it's a bit hard to suggest anything

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Seems like such basic code I thought maybe this is a new bug or something... I updated the question

Comment: you dont' have used "map_meta_cap" in the CPT declaration, set it to TRUE :  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#map_meta_cap

Comment: You don't seem to specify the post type in wp_update_post. When you say post_type_exists returns false, where are you checking that?

Comment: @mmm thanks but setting map_meta_cap to true didnt make a difference. I should mention this is a multisite and im super admin so that caps shouldnt matter

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook if I check for the post_type_exists first it will never run because that function returns falls even though the custom posts update and insert fine. Its really strange behaviour

Comment: Are they in the admin as Courses or as Posts?

Comment: I should note the script runs fine with no errors when WordPress is fully loaded but shows these notices only when using wp-load.php

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook course. post_type_exists finds posts fine but not the custom post type course. Ive tried including the course registration code right after wp-load.php but doesnt make a difference. Again wether the custom post type course is seen or not they update and insert fine...

Comment: If your script is in your theme folder then aren't you going back up too many levels in your include?

Answer (score 1):

Today i got exactly the same behaviour when adding a custom post type. I also noticed some admin post search tools stopped working. My debug_log showed exactly the same notice.

The problem turned out to be some text before the `<?php` opening tag (top file) were I register the CPT.

Example

```
some text here<?php
/**
 * @class My_Cpt_Class
 */
.......
```

The CPT does get registered correctly. I can add posts etc. But a few default post actions (from other plugins aswell) stop working for ALL post types. I have no idea why this happens with this error.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if a post is encountered with a post type that you haven't registered on the `init` event.

I always call `register_post_type()` on `init`, as instructed in the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). However, in my dev build process I use `wp-cli` to deactivate my plugin, and re-install the new iteration of the plugin. In the brief moment when the plugin is deactivated, this message appears because WP runs without the post type being registered.

In short, WordPress shows this error whenever it sees a post with a post type that's not properly registered.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this kind of error.

One of the reasons that I faced was when I had data saved in comments tables but those plugins that created those data wasn't activated so the debugging tool was showing this kind of error after activating the plugin the error was gone.

By looking into your case I think it's the priority issue. Instead of using priority 0, try the default priority 10

`add_action( 'init', 'child_post_types', 10 );`

That might solve things.

Answer (score -2):

This answer might be old on this post but I hope it can help others:

I had this trouble and I solved it using this.

For example: 
I used `add_action('init', 'register_posttype');`
and that gives me the error map_meta_cap incorrectly called. so I changed it to `admin_init` instead of `init`.